# Lookup between columns on different dataframes with if condition (Pandas)

Tags: pandas, conditional-statements, lookup

I have a dataframe that is structured like this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'animal': ['lab', 'hound', 'terrier', 'retriever', 'sparrow', 'robin', 'blue jay', 'hawk'],
               'type': ['dog', 'dog', 'dog', '', 'bird','bird', '', '']})
```

And other dataframe structured like this:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'animal': ['retriever','hawk'],
               'type': ['dog','bird']})
```

I want to do a conditional look up on the 'type' column on df1 so that the output is a new column in df1 populated with the following logic so it looks like this:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'animal': ['lab', 'hound', 'terrier', 'retriever', 'sparrow', 'robin', 'blue jay', 'hawk'],
               'type': ['dog', 'dog', 'dog', '', 'bird','bird', '', ''],
                'type2': ['dog', 'dog', 'dog', 'dog', 'bird','bird', '', 'bird']})
```

- if value in df1['type'] populate this value in new column df1['type2'}
- if not, do a look up on df2 and if there is a matching value populate this value in df1['type2]
- if not, leave df1['type2'] null

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use map here with fillna:

```
df1['type2'] = df1['animal'].map(df2.set_index('animal')['type']).fillna(df1['type'])
```

Or:

```
out = df1.merge(df2,on='animal',suffixes=('','_'),how='left')
df1['type2'] = out['type_'].fillna(out['type']).rename('type2')
```

---

```
print(df1)

      animal  type type2
0        lab   dog   dog
1      hound   dog   dog
2    terrier   dog   dog
3  retriever         dog
4    sparrow  bird  bird
5      robin  bird  bird
6   blue jay            
7       hawk        bird
```

Comment: I think you did it backwards - OP stated first take from `df1['type']`, then if there's empty string take respective `df2['type']` and not other way around...

Comment: @GrzegorzSkibinski I see what you mean. Good point.

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick:

```py
import numpy as np

# build lookup table for all animals from df1, based on df2:
df2 = df2.set_index("animal").reindex(df1["animal"].unique()).fillna("")

df1["type2"] = np.where(df1["type"].str.len()>0, df1["type"], df2["type"].loc[df1["animal"]].reset_index(drop=True))
```

Outputs:

```py
      animal  type type2
0        lab   dog   dog
1      hound   dog   dog
2    terrier   dog   dog
3  retriever         dog
4    sparrow  bird  bird
5      robin  bird  bird
6   blue jay
7       hawk        bird
```